# Change SQL query when limit comes to 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a portfolio in my website in PHP, and in this portfolio i have 3 galleries. In the portfolio page i have the preview of the galleries with 4 images of each. I got a query to bring the images, but it bring me the same imgs in the 3 galleries, instead of bringing me different images in different galleries (since the galleries are different).

I got the columns galleries and themes, and i want to make the `select` query to everything, and when it reaches 4 first images of gallerie 1, it goes to the 4 first of galleries two.

An example:

```
$galeria_1 = $conexao->consultarDados("select * from portfolio where gal = 1 and theme = '{$tem}' limit 4"); //i want to make the query so when it reaches the four results, it search the same but with gal = 2;
```

Comment: If I understood your problem, in your 3 galleries you always get the same photos ? Why dont you add a "type" column to your table, then you would be able to select what kind of photos you want

Comment: 'Cause the table is working fine the way it is, the problem is that when my function load the galleries it loads 3 with same images, and i need 3 with differente images... i don't see how a new column would help.

Comment: You could use a Union.  But unless you know exactly how many galleries there are all the time that wont help.  The other way is to use a Stored Procedure, it would first get the count of galleries and then union the queries to get you a result.

Comment: Did you understand how "LIMIT" works ? if you use LIMIT 4 then you will get the 4 first results, if you use LIMIT 4,10 you will get the 10 next results

Comment: @ThomasP1988 Yes but it won't help either, 'cause it keep passing always the first four to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a table that looks like this:

```
create table portfolio (
  gal numeric,
  theme numeric,
  val numeric
);
```

And data that looks like this:

```
insert into portfolio values (1,10,1);
insert into portfolio values (1,10,2);
insert into portfolio values (1,10,3);
insert into portfolio values (1,10,4);
insert into portfolio values (1,10,5);

insert into portfolio values (2,10,1);
insert into portfolio values (2,10,2);
insert into portfolio values (2,10,3);
insert into portfolio values (2,10,4);
insert into portfolio values (2,10,5);

insert into portfolio values (3,10,1);
insert into portfolio values (3,10,2);
insert into portfolio values (3,10,3);
insert into portfolio values (3,10,4);
insert into portfolio values (3,10,5);

insert into portfolio values (4,10,1);
insert into portfolio values (4,10,2);
insert into portfolio values (4,10,3);
insert into portfolio values (4,10,4);
insert into portfolio values (4,10,5);
```

You can run a query like this:

```
select *
from (
  select p.*
  , (@rowNum:=Case when @lastGal=p.gal then @rowNum+1 else 1 end) as rowNumber
  , (@lastGal:=p.gal) as currentGal
  from portfolio p, (SELECT @rowNum := 0, @lastGal := 0) r
) q
where rowNumber <= 4
order by gal, val;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf65/1

`SELECT @rowNum := 0, @lastGal := 0` is joined to the query to create two variables: `@rowNum`  to store the row number, and `@lastGal`  for the gallery number of the previous row. If the current gallery is the same as the last row we increment the row number, otherwise we reset it to 1.

This simulates the `row_number() over Partition` functionality available in SQL Server but not in MySQL. It assigns a number to each row in each group (where a group is the set of rows for a gallery), and then the WHERE clause limits the results so that only the first four row numbers for each group are shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a for loop, iterate over the 12 images of the 3 galeries, dunno if this is what you are looking for

```
$j = 1;
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    if($j == 1){//first time
         $galeria_1 = $conexao->consultarDados("select * from portfolio where gal = \''.$j.'\' and theme = '{$tem}' limit 4");
         $j++;

         //do stuff with four images gal 1

    } else if($i%4){
         $galeria_1 = $conexao->consultarDados("select * from portfolio where gal = \''.$j.'\' and theme = '{$tem}' limit 4");
         $j++;

         //do stuff four images gal x

    }        
}
```